# How to access a Tcl package option in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, tcl

I was reading about `msgcat`'s [package options](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/msgcat.html#M38).

How do I get, set and update these values?

I tried these:

```py
root.eval("::msgcat::mcfolder")    # _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "::msgcat::mcfolder"
```

```py
root.globalgetvar("::msgcat::mcfolder")    # _tkinter.TclError: can't read "::msgcat::mcfolder": no such variable
```

```py
root.option_get("mcfolder", "msgcat")    # ''
```

*where root is a `tkinter.Tk` instance*.

I am not finding any info about this in Tcl docs either *or I didn't look closely*.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your code's problem? Are the return values wrong? Does nothing happen? Do you get error messages? Please ***[edit] your question*** to include these details.

Comment: The page you linked tells you how; it's literally just the previous subsection from the one you linked to. (It tells you in a Tcl style, but that's to be expected for a Tcl-related package.)

Comment: @DonalFellows I got that eventually, I initially thought it is a concept in Tcl, but its just a msgcat-specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that this isn't a Tcl-wide concept, but just something `msgcat` does, so:

```py
root.eval("::msgcat::mcpackageconfig get mcfolder")
```

works when `mcload` is already called or `mcfolder` is set.